# How to handle run time error in the below code? I am writing a code to find first digit of a number in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    //write your code here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t;
    t = sc.nextInt();
    while (t!=0){
      int a;
      a = sc.nextInt();
      while (a>10)
        a/=10;

        System.out.println(+a);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the exception and the stack trace. --- As an aside: your program will either never enter the loop or run indefinetly.

Comment: If you want to handle the exception, in this method itself, then do not use throws keyword. Surround your method body with try catch block. In the catch argument, you can give Exception e and then inside your catch body, you can print the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to handle an exception you've got to surround it with try/catch block. Here's the code if you want to find first digit of a number:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]){

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        boolean state = true;
        while (state) {
            if ((number >= 10) || (number <= -10)) {
                number /= 10;
            } else {
                if (number < 0) {
                    number *= -1;
                    System.out.println(number);
                    state = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(number);
                    state = false;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Your input doest match");
    }
}
}
```